# How to trigger the display of the Windows calendar popup that shows up when the clock in the taskbar is clicked?

Tags: windows, windows-10, calendar

There's a calendar that pops up when you click the time in the Windows taskbar.

[image]

Is there any other way to trigger its display rather than having to click on the clock in the taskbar? Perhaps through a command line or something similar?

I have a Rainmeter clock and I would much rather have it show up on clicking it instead, so that I can hide the clock in the taskbar altogether.